# Delphi XE2 app doesn't respond on IPAD

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, delphi, delphi-xe2

I try to use Delphi XE2 for develop for an iPad 3 professional application.
The configuration is ok.
I work on a MacBook Pro with Windows 7 on VMWare.
I create an HD app for iOS.
I put a timer, two labels and a button.
The timer refresh the time on label1 and the "on_click" event of the button change the label of label2.
It's compiled with Delphi.
I export to Xcode in the shared folder.
I launch Xcode and try with the iPad simulator.
All is ok.
I try to run on a real iPad, the application is launched but:
* the form is shown as a very small panel
* the timer seems not working but if i rotate the IPAD, the screen is refreshed and the time is shown.
* MY MAIN PROBLEM: if i tap on the button nothing happens.
I tried a lot of events, all works in delphi, in iPad simulator but not on the real iPad.

So, what the good options for fire events on a iPad ?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I try to run the same application on a iPhone 4S and it works fine!
The trouble is only on iPad 3. I haven't no iPad 1 or 2 for testing.

Comment: Just in case you did not, check http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41620 and http://www.itwriting.com/blog/4841-hands-on-with-delphi-xe2-for-apple-ios.html. I suspect your problem might have something to do with some components appearing in the tool palette but not being really supported for iOS (warning given in 2nd article)

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I check also http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Components_Not_Used_in_iOS_Apps from Embarcadero main site but the few components used seems to be compatible with iOS deployement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this trouble.
The installation of Delphi XE2 update 4 need to have XCODE 4.2 installed.
If you don't have it you can't install FireMonkey-iOS.dmg.
You must have too the latest version of XCODE 4.3.2 in parallels.
Of course, BE CAREFUL, of what version of Xcode is launched!
It easily to understand that for used the new IPAD (3) you must used at least Xcode 4.3.2.
If you use Xcode 4.2, your project will be compiled, running but now responding, because it don't know about iPad 3.
Enjoy.